# How can I save data to my backend by using DocuSign Connect?

Tags: docusignapi

I am using DocuSign for signatures. For auto notifications I am using DocuSign Connect. For that I am using a public url.

Actually, I want to store in my backend system but it can connect only within our network. So from the public url I am posting to my backend.

It is not giving error but  data is not going there.

```
$test = file_get_contents('php://input');

$xml1 = simplexml_load_string($test);
$data = $xml1[0]->EnvelopeStatus->Status;


    $curl = curl_init("http://xxxxx.xxx.xxx");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/plain'));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    $json_response1 = curl_exec($curl);
```

This is my Listener page.

I am unable to connect to my db. When I try the same code in my localhost it is executing.

How can I save data to my backend from DocuSign Connect?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question:

Your code is able to save to your backend when it runs on your localhost, but does not work when you run it on your Internet-visible host.

In that case, the problem is a difference between your localhost and your Internet-visible host. This type of problem is common.

Start with checking communications between the Internet-visible host and the backend. (Can you ping between the two?)

Then debug further. What error are your getting from Curl? What do the logs show on your backend machine?

I suggest that you involve the IT people who set up your DMZ. You may need your IT dept to create a "pinhole" in your firewall to enable communications between the Internet-visible host and your backend.